# render conditional vue component based on browser size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive-design, nuxt.js

i'm looking for way to use responsive component in vue js (nuxt).

i created this *mixin* but i get error:

```
export const mediaQuery = {
  data() {
    return {
      breakpoints: {
        sm: 576,
        md: 768,
        lg: 992,
        xl: 1200
      },
      windowWidth: 0,
      currentBreakpoint: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (process.browser) {
      this.setWindowWidth()
      this.setCurrentBreakpoint()

      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.setWindowWidth()
        this.setCurrentBreakpoint()
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    smPlus() {
      return this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.sm
    },
    smMinus() {
      return this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.md
    },
    mdPlus() {
      return this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.md
    },
    mdMinus() {
      return this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.lg
    },
    lgPlus() {
      return this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.lg
    },
    lgMinus() {
      return this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.xl
    },
    xlPlus() {
      return this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.xl
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setWindowWidth() {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
    },
    setCurrentBreakpoint() {
      if (this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.sm) {
        this.currentBreakpoint = 'xs'
      } else if (
        this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.sm &&
        this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.md
      ) {
        this.currentBreakpoint = 'sm'
      } else if (
        this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.md &&
        this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.lg
      ) {
        this.currentBreakpoint = 'md'
      } else if (
        this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.lg &&
        this.windowWidth < this.breakpoints.xl
      ) {
        this.currentBreakpoint = 'lg'
      } else if (this.windowWidth >= this.breakpoints.xl) {
        this.currentBreakpoint = 'xl'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is error:
**Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

and i don't know what is the solution

totally how should we use responsive components?

i don't want to use media query in this situation.

thank you

Comment: i think the problem is not in the code you posted. is more in the template code. that  the code who really touch the dom (which trigger the error). and btw when you bind to window resize event a function inside component (call it). you should remove it when the component destory. otherwise you will probably got a error because the `this` function dosent exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I would say problem would be that your SSR result dont  match client result. use mounted hook to set your breakpoints instead of created